# calculate total sum from first month to the last month

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2017

How to calculate total sum value from first month to the last?

Example:

[image: i want it to be like this]

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't showing the output like the example above.

```
select 
    left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6) MONTH,
    sum(AMOUNTVALUE) TOTAL_A,
    sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) TOTAL_B,
    sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) + sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) TOTAL_C
from tx_details txd
    inner join TX_SELISIH txs 
        on txd.TXID=txs.TXID 
            and txd.OFFICEID=txs.OFFICEID
where txd.operationaldate BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20201231'
    and TXDATE>'20190831' 
    and SELISIHTYPE=1
GROUP BY left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6)
```

Is it even possible to get the result like that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SUM ( Sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) + sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) ) OVER ( ORDER BY left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6) )`

Comment: @Squirrel thank you for your response sir, i use your code and modify it to SUM ( Sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE)  ) OVER ( ORDER BY left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6) )

and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this:

```
SELECT 
    left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6) MONTH,
    sum(AMOUNTVALUE) TOTAL_A,
    sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) TOTAL_B,
    SUM ( Sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) + sum(10*AMOUNTVALUE) ) OVER ( ORDER BY left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6) ) TOTAL_C
from tx_details txd
    inner join TX_SELISIH txs 
        on txd.TXID=txs.TXID 
            and txd.OFFICEID=txs.OFFICEID
where txd.operationaldate BETWEEN '20200101' AND '20201231'
    and TXDATE>'20190831' 
    and SELISIHTYPE=1
GROUP BY left(convert(varchar,txd.OPERATIONALDATE,112),6)
```